# Why don't I have the contains in linQ when I'm using datetime?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to get this query to linQ but I don't see the contains when I invoke the date.

Query:

```
SELECT *    
FROM [ReplicacionSigob].[dbo].[v_cbs01] 
where tramite_fecha_fin like '%2017-04-11%'
```

Linq:

[image]

Comment: `tramite_fecha_fin` seems to be a `Nullable<DateTime>` while `Contains` is for collections.

Comment: `tramite_fecha_fin` is a nullable `DateTime`, right?

Comment: yes, it is @dasblinkenlight

Comment: If you use  `LIKE` with *dates* you have some serious design and performance bugs already. Using `LIKE` with a date is completely meaningless and **guaranteed** to return bad results due to the localized conversion from date to string, *and* the comparison with the locale-specific string. If you wanted all entries in a date, use `where cast(datefield as date) =  @myDateTypedParam`. If you have to hard-code the date value, use an unseparated literal `20170411`

Comment: oh ok, thanks @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Since `tramite_fecha_fin` is a `Nullable<DateTime>`, not a `string`, you cannot use `contains` on it to translate to SQL's `LIKE` operator. You shouldn't do it in SQL either, because date/time formatting impacts correctness, and the need to convert to string creates performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

`Contains` is only for collections or strings, what you want to do is this:

```
var queryFecha = (from c in _context.v_cbs01
                  where c.tramite_fecha_fin.HasValue 
                     && c.tramite_fecha_fin.Value.Date == new DateTime(2011, 04, 11)
                  select c);
```